# Way to load mvcc tables automatically when DolphinDB starts?

Tags: startup, dolphindb

I create the following 3 mvcc tables

```
n=5
syms=`IBM`C`MS`MSFT`JPM`ORCL`FB`GE
timestamp=09:30:00+rand(18000,n)
sym=rand(syms,n)
qty=100*(1+rand(100,n))
price=5.0+rand(100.0,n)
temp=table(timestamp,sym,qty,price)
t1= mvccTable(1:0,`timestamp`sym`qty`price,[TIMESTAMP,SYMBOL,INT,DOUBLE],"/home/xjqian/mvcctables","t1")
t1.append!(temp);
t2= mvccTable(1:0,`timestamp`sym`qty`price,[TIMESTAMP,SYMBOL,INT,DOUBLE],"/home/xjqian/mvcctables","t2")
t2.append!(temp);
t3= mvccTable(1:0,`timestamp`sym`qty`price,[TIMESTAMP,SYMBOL,INT,DOUBLE],"/home/xjqian/mvcctables","t3")
t3.append!(temp);
```

Is there any way to automatically load all these tables when DolphinDB is started?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script can be used to get all table names and load the tables:

```
login(`admin,`123456)
tables=select * from files("/home/xjqian/mvcctables") where isDir=true
for (tableName in tables.filename){
       share( loadMvccTable("/home/xjqian/mvcctables",tableName) , "share_"+tableName)
}
```

Add it to the startup script *startup.dos,* so the tables can be loaded when the system is started. See the [Startup Scripts](https://github.com/dolphindb/Tutorials_EN/blob/master/startup.md) for more information.

You can check whether the tables are loaded with `objs(true)`:

```
select * from objs(true) where name like "share_%"
```

See the queried result:

```
name    type    form    rows    columns bytes   shared  extra
share_t1    MVCC    TABLE   5   4   368 true    
share_t2    MVCC    TABLE   5   4   368 true    
share_t3    MVCC    TABLE   5   4   368 true
```